# Abort Ajax call and show else block in JSP as explained

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am new to coding and learning quickly. I have a situation here and i need some suggestions from experts here.

So i have a jsp like:

```
if(something){
    //render content from js file here through ajax call
}else{
    //java code here
}
```

In a seperate js file i am doing an ajax call and rendering the content if the if condition is satisfied. Else i need to show the else block. Here in the ajax call i will get an error in some cases (Ex: file to parse in JSON is not available in the server, which will return in the error). So i need to show the else block in the jsp file.

JS:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url1.trim(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
     // render content in if block with some HTML
    },
    error: function(xhr,status) {
      //abort the ajax call here and show the else block in jsp code
    }
   });
```

Please can any one provide how to solve this situation. I am still in learning stages. the only thing i can think of here is to abort the ajax call and go to else block in jsp. Is there a better way to solve this? If not how can we go to else block in jsp. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if there is a need to elaborate the question. i will try to explain it whatever is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL EL for your jsp file.

```html
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${condition1}">
  <script>...</script> //js script to execute
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    //java code here
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Hi @aholake. thanks a lot for your response. But your response is to just an alternative to if else block using jstl. but it doesnt show how to abort an ajax call and come back to show the else back of jsp. Please edit your answer or let me know if the question is not clear. I will try to explain it better.

Comment: you cannot mix them together, simply because the java conditions are execute in server side, but the script is executed in client. There is a way to work around is after receiving the result of ajax call, you pass this result to server and then reload page once.

Answer (score 0):

How about displaying the "else" content in a hidden div. You would then show that div when the condition is false or when the ajax call returns an error.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${something}">
                $('#waitDiv').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url1.trim(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#contentDiv').html(data).show();
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status) {
                        $('#contentDiv').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#waitDiv').hide();
                    }
                });
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                $('#contentDiv').show();
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    });
</script>

<div id="waitDiv" style="display: none;">
Please wait.
</div>

<div id="contentDiv" style="display: none;">
This is the content to display when the condition is false
or the ajax call fails. This content will get replaced if
the ajax call succeeds.
</div>
```

Initially the `contentDiv` is hidden, but if the condition is false, it will be displayed as soon the page-ready handler executes.

If the condition is true, the `waitDiv` is displayed and the ajax call is made. If the ajax call is successful, the returned content is placed in `contentDiv` and `contentDiv` is displayed. If the ajax call fails, the `contentDiv` is displayed with the "else" content. In either case, the `waitDiv` is hidden.

Note: You aren't aborting the ajax call when it returns an error. The ajax call finished, it just wasn't successful.

Comment: Hi @JohnS . Thanks for the response. I got the same idea. But i have the same divs in if and else condition so cant use hide attribute :(

Comment: @StackAcc - I have updated my answer to show how you could have the ajax call use the same div as the else condition.

Comment: Sorry. I have same divs with same id's as we will be displaying only one section. So cant use hide and show :( any other alternative please?

Comment: @StackAcc - I think you might not be following what the code in my answer does, so I have added to the answer. It is not really doing a hide/show. The same div is displayed in all cases. The displaying of it is just delayed if an ajax call is made. Also, it gets different content if the ajax call succeeds.